# linearization of non-linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

We have a non-linear ODE of the form

$ \dot x= f(x, h(x))$

where $g(x, h(x))=0$, $h: X\subseteq\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m$, $g:\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^m\to \mathbb R^m$, $f:\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^m\to \mathbb R^n$ are smooth, could anyone tell me how the matrix of linearized ODE is formed as: $A=D_xf-D_yf(D_yg)^{-1}D_xg)_{|(x^*, h(x^*))}$ where $D_x$ denote the Jacobian w.r.t $x$. and $x^*$ is a stable point. Thank you! If you could give me a proper reference about how to find linearization of such ODE that would be nice too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to read up on the Schur-complement.
Or linearize the DAE system directly
\begin{align}
\dot u &=D_xf(x^*,y^*)u+D_yf(x^*,y^*)v,\\
0&=D_xg(x^*,y^*)u+D_yg(x^*,y^*)v,
\end{align}
$y^*=h(x^*)$, and use the second equation to eliminate $v$ from the first equation.

Comment: Thanks, Lutz, Could I get a link? what is $u,v$

Comment: For the inverse of a block matrix, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement. $u,v$ are the displacements of $x,y$ close to the equilibrium. Or the first terms in a perturbation expansion $x=x^*+\epsilon u+O(\epsilon^2)$ etc.